# Infinite undo/redo system for color/width of an object

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I made an undo/redo system but it forgets the width and color. It draws all objects with the last color and width (last configuration (saw at initialize)).

I need a suggestion on how to save the color and width.

Here is link:
http://pastebin.com/jBVJya8a

Answer (score 0):

You could save the `color` and weight as `SharedPreferences` for your application. SharedPrefernces are saved for when you run your app again. Here's a tutorial link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: emm but i must save a lot of different things, what do you think??

Comment: If you have really a lot, you would go for a database. It depends on the design of your app. If you have say, up to 100 values then SharedPreference. Or you can save to internal or external storage. Depends on your design.